# how can i invoke my logout hook code in my whmcs?

Tags: php, client, whmcs

```
<?php
function logout_intercom{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> Intercom('shutdown'); </script>";
    die();
}
add_hook('ClientLogout', 1, 'logout_intercom');
?>
```

In this above code was written as seprate `hooks.php` file, and i need to make invoke this code while client gets logout.
There fore I need a code that invoking my code into whmcs while whmcs client gets logout.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_hook('UserLogout', 1, function($vars)
{
    header('Location: "The url you want redirect post logout"');
    exit; 
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it